# Nifi || Can we execute multiple sql queries in single database session

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a requirement in which i have to execute multiple sql queries in Nifi using executesql processor.

Those queries are dependent on each other as I am storing data in session based temporary table.

So I need to know if I do so , whether all the queries will get executed in single database session.

Example:

Query a data is inserted into Temp_A, Now I need that data in next query so will it be possible.

Note: I am talking about session based Temporary table only.

Comment: did you try `PutSQL` to insert data into Temp_A table and then using `ExecuteSQL` to get that data?

Comment: yes..,. I tried but didn't succeed.
It showing relation does not exist.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Vertica database

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ExecuteSQL` processor where in `SQL Pre-Query` parameter that could contain multiple commands separated with semicolon `;`

all those commands with main sql query will be executed using the same connection for one flow file.

note that the same sql connection could be used for the next flow file.

Comment: I have used the same, where in I put all the insert queries in Pre Query with comma separated while in select query i wrote the main query. But still I am getting the error as Relation does not exist.

Comment: this sounds like path / schema issue in vertica. try something like this in your main query to understand schema name for your temp table `select table_schema from tables where table_name = 'Temp_A'`

Comment: I was successful in executing the same and got v_temp_schema as output for specified query.
now how to succeed for the same as when I am putting the select query it is displaying relation does not exist.